# How To Overcome CORS issues with Redux React Express and Node?

Tags: express, reactjs, redux, react-router, react-redux

I have a React App that uses React Router and Redux as its state manager. The server side of the app uses Express and Node.

I am making API calls to an external service. I do not have the ability to enable CORS on the external service. Therefore, I need to use my app's server side to make the calls to the external service to remove the browser from the equation, and eliminate any CORS error.

I am able to get my data from the service on the server side successfully. I would like to know if it is possible to share the Redux store in between the client and server with some sort of middleware (looking for examples/resources).

**The goal:**

1) Handle a click event in the client

2) Have that event call a server side route to external api (don't know how to do this)

3) Then the server handles this route, makes the request, and sends the response to the client (through the shared react store - not sure if this is possible)

4) The store gets the new state, and then sends to the client side components, and the UI updates

Are there any examples/tutorials of this? Not looking for an initial server rendered page, but guides that inform how the above 4 steps can generally be implemented.

Comment: which library are you using for making API requests? superagent/fetch?

Comment: checkout this example that I'm currently building, already has support for universal react/redux app: https://github.com/alexnm/react-seed. Also if you want to check a more complex example, I suggest the MERN starter: https://github.com/Hashnode/mern-starter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for the suggestions.

It turns out that I was severely over thinking the solution. All I really needed was the ability to launch a server side function (get resources from external API) from the client side event (load component). Sort of like how submitting a form, has an action that launches a server side function.

In my component:

```
componentDidMount() {
    const product_api_results = productApi.getProductItems()
    console.log('product_api_results in CART Component: ', product_api_results)
    /* now I have results and can put it in the Redux Store via action to reducer for other components to work with on client */
  }
```

The productAPI.getProductItems() that the component calls:

```
export function getProductItems () {
  return axios.get('/api/get-products') // triggers a server side route
    .then(function (response) {
      console.log('client side response: ', response)
      return response
    })
}
```

In Express server.js file, the server will see this url and then get the proper data. The `shopify.get()` is from the shopify-node-api module:

```
app.get('/api/get-products', function (req, res) { // '/api/get-products' called from client
  shopify.get('/admin/products.json', function (err, data, headers) {
    res.send(data)
  })
})
```